# Javascript Bind Intricacies

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, bind

I am not a newbie to Javascript by any means; that is to say I have a basic understanding of what bind does and how it behaves. However, I came across a use-case where I was a bit unsure of the result.
Let me elaborate on a sample setup :

#### Sample Setup

First, I have a function (callback) that will be bound in other functions (api routes). (It currently lives in a separate file)

```
function callback(err, data) {
  ...
  this.cb(response)
}
```

As you can see, `this.cb` is passed along by the routes and is unique to them.

```
function getRouteA(args, cb) {
  this.cb = cb;
  ...
  asycDBOperationX(..., callback.bind(this))
}

function getRouteB(args, cb) {
  this.cb = cb;
  ...
  asycDBOperationY(..., callback.bind(this))
}
```

#### Questions

Now, everything works quite well as I hoped it would. However, I have certain doubts regarding this setup.

1. This being an api and all, **how do I ensure (or simply confirm) that different instances of same route have their own value of** `this.cb`**?**
   *In case getRouteA is called near simultaneously by 10 different users, will `this.cb` be polluted?*
2. AFAIK, bind creates and returns a new function with the bound context. However, it does so only once and won't work for successive binds. **If I bind the same function in n different contexts, will I get n different functions? How does it work against the rule of binding only once?**  *callback is being bound in both routeA and B, are these two different functions with their own scopes?*
3. For now, I have added an extra parameter to callback, it now looks like `(err, data, cb)` and instead of binding it in the async function, called it so : `asycDBOperationY(..., (e, d) => callback(e, d, cb))` **While this works, I am curious as to the difference between calling a shared function by parameter and by binding the context. Which one is preferred over the other and in what scenarios?**

#### Thank you :)

Comment: It's really hard to tell from the code what you're trying to achieve, particuarly the indirect callback call via `callback`. Also, what's `this` in these functions? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: "*how do I ensure (or simply confirm) that different instances of same route have their own value of `this.cb`?*" - well, how do you ensure that different instances have different `this` values? How are you calling those route functions, are they methods or constructors?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Apologies for the difficult code, I tried to simplify it as best as I could. Not sure how to simulate async DB operations in snippets though. Can't used setTimeout as it changes context.

Comment: @Bergi I do not know if different instances have different this values, that is one of the things I had doubt about. My route functions are setup similar to how a router is used in Node -> '/path/routeA' is set to getrouteA

Comment: @PriteshTupe - So does the DB operation callback. `setTimeout` is exactly how you would emulate an async DB op.

Comment: @PriteshTupe So what is `this` in a router callback at all?

Comment: @Bergi ```this``` should be the context of the calling function; ideally, different for each instance of that function. Not sure if it works that way though.

@T.J.Crowder I tried using setTimeouts out on JSBin, it gives out different outputs than what I get in my code. Please try to understand the issue from the description as I'm unable to provide a more simpler or a workable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I ensure (or simply confirm) that different instances of same route have their own value of this.cb?

You don't, thats the problem with your setup. If you do:

```
 sth.getRouteA({}, one);
 sth.getRouteA({}, two);
```

Then `two` will be called twice.

> If I bind the same function in n different contexts, will I get n different functions? How does it work against the rule of binding only once?

Yes you can bind a funcion more than once, but you cannot bind a bound function again so:

```
  cb.bind(a).bind(b)
```

will still be bound to `a`, the second bind is useless.

```
cb.bind(a)
cb.bind(b)
```

That however works as expected as a non bound function gets wrapped into two bound functions with different contexts.

> While [adding an extea parameter instead] works, I am curious as to the difference between calling a shared function by parameter and by binding the context.

The difference is that it works in opposite to the other version.

Comment: 1. If same this.variable is called twice, then this setup won't work in real world usage?
2. Not sure I understand the difference - works in opposite to other version? In what way, can you please elaborate?

Thanks